# Nested foreach conversion to LINQ with a condition on two lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

LINQ is like voodo magic to me. No need to show you what I've done, nothing works or even compiles, I'm just getting error in a somewhat not understandable language:

`The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

So, here's my code:

```
foreach (string first in firstStrings)
    foreach (string second in secondStrings)
    {
        try {
            if (second.Contains(DoFormatting(first)))
                DoStuff(first, second);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogStuff(first, second);
        }
    }
```

**(How) can I translate it to Linq?**

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Why do you want to translate it to LINQ?

Comment: Use LINQ to enhance readability. In this particular case, it would only make a multiple-line mess.

Comment: @Kristof: educational purposes, I'm getting tired of nested foreach loops.

Comment: I wouldn't use LINQ for code that's just about the 'side effects' (such as calling DoStuff and discarding its return value). With LINQ, a lot of code is executed only when needed, e.g. when you're iterating the results of a query. But what results would you iterate over in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following to reduce it down to one `foreach`, but honestly you might as well leave it as is.

```
var pairs = from first in firstStrings
            from second in secondStrings
            select new 
            { 
                first, 
                second
            };

foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    try 
    {
        if (pair.second.Contains(DoFormatting(pair.first)))
            DoStuff(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogStuff(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
}
```

OR with extension methods

```
var pairs = firstStrings.Join(
    secondStrings, 
    x=>true, 
    y=>true, 
    (first, second) => new { first, second});

foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    try 
    {
        if (pair.second.Contains(DoFormatting(pair.first)))
            DoStuff(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogStuff(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
}
```

I would not use a `ForEach` extension method because enumerating over an enumeration and creating side effects is against the best practices of using Linq.

Comment: This is the closest example of what I would use if using Linq wasn't such a mess in my case.

Comment: @Kilazur - linq itself is not a mess, it's just that you're trying to replace a very fine-grained function that does several things (exception handling, logging, filtering, permutation handling) into a single query and that's more difficult.  The exception handling and filtering of permutations are what throw the monkey wrench into things.

Comment: Hence "in my case" :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to you could create an extension method as below:

```
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (T item in enumeration)
            {
                action(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then use LINQ as follows:

```
 firstStrings.ForEach(first => secondStrings.ForEach(second =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (second.Contains(DoFormatting(first)))
                        {
                            DoStuff(first, second);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        LogStuff(first, second);
                    }
                }));
```

But, as other commentors have mentioned, I would keep your code as is (at least in regard to whether you convert it to LINQ).

Comment: btw, there is already [a method on List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) that does exacly the same.

Comment: Yea, but not on IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Ok well, basically it doesn't add much interesting stuff. So the (almost) right answer is no, I can't translate it to Linq.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really translate much of it to Linq because you still have to iterate over all of the permutation, which requires two separate nested loops.

You could do this, it doesn't save a lot, but some:

```
foreach (string first in firstStrings)
    try {
        foreach (var second in secondStrings.Where(second => second.Contains(DoFormatting(first))))
           DoStuff(first, second);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LogStuff(first, second);
    }
```

EDIT:

Note that the logging here would have to change because second is not available in the catch block, which is a problem with moving things to linq.. you have less access to which item in the collection caused the error.  You would probably have to move the exception handling into both DoFormtting and DoStuff.

And, as juharr pointed out, if an exception is thrown it will terminate processing of secondStrings rather than continuing to the next.  So that may not be the desired function either..  again, a side effect of moving to linq, you lose the ability to do fine grained exception handling and continuation.

Comment: Yeah, replacing two foreach + one if with two foreach + linq... Indeed, this is hardly minimizable. But at least this version remains readable enough.

Comment: Moving the try-catch outside of the inner foreach will result in different behavior.  If an exception is thrown you could end up with fewer calls to `DoStuff`.  And moving it inside of this inner foreach would not catch exceptions in `DoFormatting`.

Comment: @juharr - true, and this code doesn't actually work anyways, as the exception would not be able to access second... Of course that's one of the drawbacks of linq is that it's harder to know which item in the collection caused the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that LINQ was designed using principles of functional programming, and the big principle there is to not cause side effects.

That said there are some things you can do, using a combination of juharr and Erik's approaches
this would work:

```
        var ContainedPairs=
            firstStrings.Join(secondStrings, 
                              x => true, 
                              y => true, 
                             (first, second) => new { first, second })
                         .Where(pairs => pairs.second.Contains(DoFormatting(pairs.first)));

//loop over pairs calling dostuff and error handling
```

Note that the important thing here is that DoFormatting must be guaranteed not to change pairs.first, and not to throw an error.

If this is not the case then changing the signature of DoFormatting to the following:

```
private bool ContainsFormatted(string first, string second, out Exception ex)
```

would allow you to do this:

```
        var pairResults =
            firstStrings.Join(secondStrings, 
                              x => true, 
                              y => true, 
                              (first, second) => new { first, second })
                        .Select(pair =>
                                {
                                    Exception ex = null;
                                    var containsFormatted = ContainsFormatted(pair.second, pair.first, out ex);
                                    return new { pair, containsFormatted, ex };
                                });
//loop over pair results, calling DoStuff on items where containsFormatted = true and logging exceptions etc otherwise
```

The point here is that side effects and error handling are still left out of linq, but that doesn't mean that you need to give up the benefits of a more functional style of programming

Comment: Interesting approach, but it remains quite hard to understand at first glance. Linq clearly is not designed for this kind of methods.

Comment: Agreed, the first approach is what I prefer to see, in which case, DoFormatting needs to be designed with that in mind. Linq is un-ashamedly functional in nature, so code needs to be designed with that in mind. Another example is that Linq makes it easier to deal with empty collections rather than null's. There are a few technologies that are similar to linq in terms of composibility but that do handle error handling logic: Reactive Extentions(Rx) and TPL Dataflow

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at Lambda expressions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397675.aspx

So, the LINQ translation would look something like this

```
String result = second.Where( r => r.Contains(first));
```

Comment: Doesn't `Where` return a list?

Comment: @Kilazur `Where` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` in this case.

Comment: Moreover, this will just return a list containing elements from `second`, when I also need elements from `first`.

Comment: Yes, you are both correct. I should have been more specific. My real point was to direct @Oren toward Lambda expressions, which should give him the information he needs. My example would need a Join() and a correction of the type for result.